# how to forward request in login controller to next page?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

this is my controller class

```
@Controller
public class loginController {

  @RequestMapping("/hello")  
    public ModelAndView helloWorld(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse res) {  
        String name=request.getParameter("name");  
        String password=request.getParameter("password");  

        if(password.equals("admin")){  
        String message = "HELLO "+name;  
        return new ModelAndView("hellopage", "message", message);  
        }  
        else{ return new ModelAndView("errorpage", "message","Sorry, username or password error");  
        }  
    }  

}
```

Comment: web-xml-
<servlet>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>  web.xml file

Comment: <context:component-scan base-package="controller.loginController"></context:component-scan>
<bean class ="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
<property name="prefix" value ="/WEB-INF/jsp" />
<property name="suffix" value =".jsp" />
</bean> dispatcher servlet.xml file

Comment: when we run the project only index .jsp work then after getting 404

Comment: i also point debbug point but its not working

Comment: Can you add more information about what's happening?
What's your intended outcome?

Comment: i have done to solve the problem but one more requirement is this i want to save this user id and password in database so i use config in spring.xml where i use this code this is my first step --<bean id="ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"></property>
<property name="username" value="system"></property>
<property name="password" value="12345"></property>
</bean>

Comment: in my controller how to use user name and pass to save this db please help me

Comment: @kewne i dnt use any hibernate config i want simple oracle db to save the database

Comment: if you've solved the problem please post your solution so others can benefit from it too.

Regarding the saving part, I think it's more appropriate to create a new question.

Comment: actually sir its my mistake i use another jsp page which is not in use so thats why its not working